# How can I make an iOS app communicate with Mac server app counterpart?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift, server

as the title suggests I would like to make a connection between an iOS app and a Mac OS X app that will be the server. I just want to send simple encoded strings to and from the iOS app but I have searched for ways to communicate and nothing specific has shown up. Can you please point me to the right direction (e.g. documentation for a class to use)? An example if possible? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is the iOS device and the Mac on the same network? If so you might be looking for this.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html

Comment: **thank you** very much Skyler Lauren! That's exactly what I was looking for but didn't know how to search.

Comment: You might also consider looking into remote notifications.  Your OSX server can push notifications to iOS clients that can have them execute in the background in response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your iOS device and Mac are going to be near each other you may want to look at this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html

However there are some limitations on what Macs and iOS devices can use this so read carefully. Hopefully that helps.